# Find x where y is minimum

Tags: python, minimum, polynomials

I have a *polynomial in a range (-2,2)*. I can easily find min y values by iterating with *x=0.1*. But I also want to find corresponding x value where y is minimum. (without using any additional libraries)

Let's say y=x**2+3*x+5. I want to find *min(y) in a range(-2,2)* and also want to find x which gives min(y).

```
def f(x):
   return x**2+3*x+5
y=[]
x=[i/10 for i in range(-20,20)]
for x in x:
   y_values.append(f1(x))

#min(y) find also minimum of y but I want to find it with long way.

   minimum1=y_values[0]
   for n in y_values: 
        if minimum1>n:
           minimum1=n
```

Comment: While `for x in x` may work, it's bad practice and can be awfully hard to debug later when you can't figure out why `x` is suddenly a single element instead of a list.

Comment: `x[y.index(min(y))`

Answer (score 2):

Since tuples are ordered by the first items and then the second items and so on, you can pass to the `min` function a generator expression that outputs tuples of `(y, x)`:

```
min((f(x), x) for x in (i / 10 for i in range(-20, 20)))
```

This returns:

```
(2.75, -1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just doing the comparison at the same time you call the function?

```
def f(x):
   return x**2+3*x+5

y=[]
x=[i/10 for i in range(-20,20)]

ymin = f1(x[0])
xmin = x[0]

for x in x:
   if(f1(x)<y):
       ymin = f1(x)
       xmin = x
   y_values.append(f1(x))
```